# Django how to get data in post that was sent with get?

Tags: python, django, post

I have a CBV that call some model methods (which run some processes on the machine, and connect to other websites to retrieve data)

```
class Edit(View:
    def get(self, request):
        object = Model.objects.get()
        object.foo()
        return object

    def post(self, request):
        ...how can I get the object here without looking it 
        up and calling the method again
```

I want to get the object again in the post method, but I do not want to call it again, because I do not want to run the process again. Is there a way I can get this info? It was passed into the template via `context`

Comment: It depends on what type of data you have in that returned object. If the data is user-specific then you could use session https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/, if it's not then you could use Django's cache https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not want to run the process again"? Those two methods are for handling different types of requests - `get` only runs for `GET` requests, and `post` for `POST` requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be an attribute of request ([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)).

```
data = request.POST # python dictionary-like
```

The view gets the argument in this order: request, positional url argument list, named url arugments as dictionary [(doc reference)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_data = request.post
    get_data = request.GET 
    non_named_url_argument_list = args 
    named_url_argument_dict = kwargs
```

Comment: I still don't see how I can retrieve the context that I sent through the get request. I see my stuff that was passed to the post request with my forms, but if I print out request.GET.items() I see very little in there, definitely not any of the information I passed to the context

Comment: ahh yes I was using the wrong kind of form and not sending the right data through with get so it was confusing me